# Integration test works with activator but not IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, playframework, sbt

I've got a junit test that came with one of the sample code projects for the Play framework which works and passes when running `activator test` from the command line but fails to run, timing out, when running as a test in IntelliJ.  I'm new to SBT, so what do I have to do to get this to work within the IDE?

Here's the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    running(testServer(3333, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, browser -> {
        browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
        assertThat(browser.pageSource(), containsString("Add Person"));
    });
}
```

Here's the error log when running in IntelliJ:

```
[[37minfo] - application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[[37minfo] - play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool - datasource [default] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[[37minfo] - application - Shutting down connection pool.

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'vtaisg708384.local', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.3', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:491)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:469)
    at org.fluentlenium.core.Fluent.goTo(Fluent.java:336)
    at IntegrationTest.lambda$test$0(IntegrationTest.java:22)
    at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:549)
    at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:535)
    at IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:178)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1313)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:338)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:407)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:480)
    ... 32 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Are you sure your local server is up and running?

Answer (score 0):

This looks as though the local server wasn't started, you may need to introduce a configuration profile in Intellij to start the server for you.

Comment: Doesn't the `running(testServer(3333, ...` do this? If not, how would I do that?

Comment: It certainly looks like it should start some instance?  I'm not real sure about that.  But checkout out https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html for setting up a Tomcat server config for example, in Intellij 15.

Comment: Another thing to consider maybe, is what is `browser` init to?  In other examples using Play I see it being set as `new Callback<TestBrowser>`

Comment: Yes, that's what `browser` is there, but it's reduced using the lambda expression (Java 8). It's the same behavior either way.